# Find a vector 90 degrees to the right of a given angle

Tags: 2d, vector, c

Can you help transform this function to move the point not only by Forward distance but also by a distance to the right or left?

```
#define FORWARD_DISTANCE 100.0

// Initialize vectors
static float vEntPosition[3]; static float vEntAngle[3]; 

// Gets the origin
....GetAbsOrigin(nEntity, vEntPosition);

// Gets the  eye angle
....GetEyeAngle(nEntity, vEntAngle);

// Calculate effect area origin
vEntPosition[0] = vEntPosition[0] + (FORWARD_DISTANCE * Cosine(DegToRad(vEntAngle[1])));
vEntPosition[1] = vEntPosition[1] + (FORWARD_DISTANCE * Sine(DegToRad(vEntAngle[1])));
```

Comment: Repeat the same thing with `(angle + pi/2)`? You might want to use the fact that `sin(a+pi/2) = cos(a)` and `cos(a+pi/2) = -sin(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your coordinate system has the y+ axis 90 degrees counter-clockwise from x+, then:

```
float angle = DegToRad(vEntAngle[1]);
float cosine = Cosine(angle);
float sine = Sine(angle);

vEntPosition[0] = vEntPosition[0]
                 + cosine * FORWARD_DISTANCE
                 + sine * RIGHTWARD_DISTANCE;

vEntPosition[1] = vEntPosition[1]
                 + sine * FORWARD_DISTANCE
                 - cosine * RIGHTWARD_DISTANCE;
```

This is a straightforward application of the unit circle - so brush up on your trigonometry and you'll find this kind of vector math can go very smoothly. :)

[image: Diagram showing how to construct unit vectors from an angle]